# strlen AVX-512 __builtin_ctz invalid value

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation, intrinsics, avx512

i wrote strlen function with avx-512 instructions and this is my source code

```
size_t avx512_strlen(const char * s) {
    __m512i vec0, vec1;
    unsigned long long mask;
    const char * ptr = s;

    vec0 = _mm512_setzero_epi32();

    while (1) {
        vec1 = _mm512_loadu_si512(s);
        mask = _mm512_cmpeq_epi8_mask(vec0, vec1);

        if(mask != 0) {
            mask = __builtin_ctz(mask);
            return (s-ptr) + mask;
        }

        s += 64;
    }

    return s-ptr;
}
```

there is a problem in the value of '__builtin_ctz(mask)' and the returned value is not correct. in fact, this function can not calculates the position of null-terminator (0x00) in the last-check

for example, i have this string

```
char str[] = "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"
                 "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"
                 "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"
                 "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE";
```

the length of this string is (360) but this function returns (352) which the problem is come from '__builtin_ctz' part. before performing '__builtin_ctz', the provided mask is correct and it's

```
0001110100010001000100010000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

in the last-check, we checked 320 characters and __builtin_ctz must returns (40) (as you can see in the mask, we count 40 zeros to first '1' and provided mask is correct and '__builtin_ctz' count it wrong !

what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__builtin_ctz` operates on `unsigned int`, which is likely 32 bits on any x86 platform.  Meanwhile, `unsigned long long` is likely 64 bits on any x86 platform.  So your mask is truncated at this line:

```
            mask = __builtin_ctz(mask);
```

Since the low 32 bits are all zero, [the result is undefined (per GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fctz):

> Returns the number of trailing 0-bits in x, starting at the least significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.

(Despite being undefined, `352 - 320 = 32` *is* a reasonable answer for "number of trailing 0 bits in a 32-bit zero integer.")

You probably meant to use `__builtin_ctzll(mask)` instead.  That should get you the correct count.

Comment: The `32` tells us GCC made asm that uses `tzcnt` https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/tzcnt, which guarantees that output.  (Instead of `bsf` where it would leave the destination register unmodified for input=0.  Intel documents BSF as "unspecified" value on input=0, but that's what it does, and why it has an output dependency.  AMD even documents it.)